# How to get rid of undefined index in this situation

Tags: php

Hi,

I have this code:

```
if($_GET['s']=="page1" || $_GET['s']=="page2" || $_GET['s']=="page3") {
 dosomething();
}
```

and I get this error: :  Undefined index: s in

Which I can dismiss only by adding this line:

```
$_GET['s']="";
```

but then this wont execute the code correctly since $_GET['s'] is not supposed to have any initial value. How do I fix this other than disabling the notices and errors?

Thank you.

Comment: Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) or [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to verify if the parameter `s` is present in the query string before using `$_GET['s']`.

Comment: @FrozenFire `in_array()` searches for values in array, it doesn't care about its keys. Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Sorry it was `array_key_exists()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your `$_GET['s']`

```
if(isset($_GET['s'])) {
  // your code goes here...
}
```

isset() is used to check if the index exists.

Comment: I get this Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Comment: Sorry code edited, I missed `)` in if condition.

Comment: Now I got like 100 notices hahahaha

Comment: Can you please update your question with new errors and mention the use of `isset()`.

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['s'])) {
 if($_GET['s']=="page1" || $_GET['s']=="page2" || $_GET['s']=="page3") {
 dosomething();
}
}`

Comment: @CainNuke Add the notices. You wouldn't enter the conditional in that case so the `s` notice wouldn't be thrown. Also `if(isset($_GET['s']) && ($_GET['s']=="page1" || $_GET['s']=="page2" || $_GET['s']=="page3")...` would be cleaner

Comment: Do a inline check and maybe you got 3 more errors.

Comment: Sorry, what 3 more errors?

Comment: Not 100 but like 2, 3 errors :D. Did `isset` solved the issue?